# Filtering Pandas Dataframe by date not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, bitcoin

I am downloading Bitcoin price data using Cryptowatch API. Downloading price data works well, but I only need price data until from 1 month ago, so data from 29.10.2019 until 28.11.2019. I read several answers to similar questions but it does not seem to work for my code as I get the same output after filtering than without filtering.

Here is my code:

```
#define 1day period
periods = '86400'

#get price data from cryptowatchAPI

resp = requests.get('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/bitfinex/btcusd/ohlc', params={'periods': periods})

resp.ok

#create pandas dataframe
data = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['result'][periods], columns=[
    'CloseTime', 'OpenPrice', 'HighPrice', 'LowPrice', 'ClosePrice', 'Volume', 'NA'])

#Make a date out of CloseTime
df['CloseTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CloseTime'], unit='s')


#make CloseTime Index of the Dataframe
df.set_index('CloseTime', inplace=True)

#filter df by date until 1 month ago
df.loc[datetime.date(year=2019,month=10,day=29):datetime.date(year=2019,month=11,day=28)]

df
```

There is no error or anything, but the output is always the same, so filtering does not work. 
Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string`s format of datetimes for filtering, check also more infornation in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing):

```
df1 = df['2019-10-29':'2019-11-28']
```

Or:

```
s = datetime.datetime(year=2019,month=10,day=29)
e = datetime.datetime(year=2019,month=11,day=28)
df1 = df[s:e]
```